# Complex data from blade to react component not showing

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-8

I have a language class in resources named - login. It has following keys.

```
return [
    "loginSuccessful"                             =>  "Login Successful",
    "invalidCredentials"                          =>  "These credentials do not match our records.",
    "inActiveAccount"                             =>  "Your account is not active. Please contact administrator.",
    "errorMessage_requiredUserNameOrEmailAddress" => "Please enter username or email address",
    "errorMessage_requiredPassword"               =>  "Please enter password",
];
```

I have a blade with following code trying to send the json data from blade to react.

```
<div messages="{!! json_encode(Lang::get('Login')) !!}" id="login"></div>
```

**Below is the login component. ** Here I am trying to read the json data in authenticate method but only getting {

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Login extends React.Component {
    authenticate() {
        var data = $("[id='login']").attr("messages");
        debugger;
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <input type="button" onClick={this.authenticate} value="Login" />
            </div>
        );
    }
    
}

export default Login;

if (document.getElementById('login')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('login'));
}
```

I was able to see the data in div. Please click image check the below screenshot..

[image]

Any idea why it just show me `{

[image]

This is how I pass language translation file from blade to vue.js... `<login v-bind:errormessages = '{!! json_encode(Lang::get("Login")) !!}'></login>`, can similar thing be done from blade to react?

Comment: I think you would need to parse it to JSON. You can see in your screenshot of the div, that it get the ```messages="{"``` and then the rest of the data. So the messages is only the things encapsulated between the double quotes.

Comment: This is how I pass language translation file from blade to vue.js... `<login v-bind:errormessages = '{!! json_encode(Lang::get("Login")) !!}'></login>`, can similar thing be done from blade to react?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I've never used blade to be fair. Can you wrap the json_encode in backticks, so it treats the object as a string?
```<div messages="{!! `json_encode(Lang::get('Login'))` !!}" id="login"></div>  ```